# phpMyAdmin - Custom Header keeps vanishing issue

Tags: php, html, css, phpmyadmin

I have been working with my new server configuration for the last few days and am developing a customer user control panel for my customers to manage their website. There is a small issue I am having now and that's with phpMyAdmin.

I upgraded the script to use the Metro theme and then modified the theme to have the css for my top bar. I then edited the `libraries/Header.class.php` file and modified the `_getBodyStart()` to include the following:

```
private function _getBodyStart()
{
    $retval = "</head><body";
    if (! empty($this->_bodyId)) {
        $retval .= " id='" . $this->_bodyId . "'";
    }
    $retval .= ">";
    $retval .= "<div id=\"portal_basic-top-bar\">
        <div class=\"top_right_links\">
            <a href=\"/?_account\" title=\"x10 Account\">Account</a>
            <a href=\"/?_logout\" title=\"Logout\">Logout</a>
        </div>
        <a href=\"/\" title=\"x10 Portal - Main\"><div class=\"title-first\"><span style=\"color: #59FF00;\">x</span>10</div> Portal</a>
    </div>";
    return $retval;
}
```

This works and shows my current title bar above the page. Yay!!

Now when i browse to another page, the code is removed somehow and I cant see it anymore. Here's a picture to explain

[image: Top bar is removed when I load new page for some reason..]
If you need me to post the css then I can. I can even make you a demo account to see the phpmyadmin over private message. Not sure whats removing it tho.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it wont work unless you load it from the `footer.class.php` since the ajax overwrites the header and removed my code from being visible. putting it in the `public function getDisplay()` right before this chunk of code:

```
        if (! $this->_isAjax) {
            $retval .= "</body></html>";
        }
```

Will allow you to add your own header to phpMyAdmin if you need a navigation bar :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should use the officially-sanctioned method of creating a `config.header.inc.php` and/or `config.footer.inc.php` (in your root phpMyAdmin folder, not the themes folder); I think you'll be able to accomplish something very close to your desired output that way, and it doesn't require making modifications directly to the codebase. This method is mentioned in the first couple of paragraphs at https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html. Note that if you're using it to load external JavaScript, you should also see https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_CSPAllow